# Python thread does not reflect changes on an object outside the update method

Tags: python, multithreading, caching

I have a main application that creates tasks to be executed by a separate thread/process (tried both).  To do that it instantiates a new Handler object and passes the task.  Later on, the main application gets additional information that needs to be added to a running task.  This information is being passed by calling a function in the Handler class called update_task.  I can see the updated version of the task inside the function, but anywhere else in the Handler class it keeps the reference to the initial object.  **How can I update the task in the running thread?**

Here is a simplified version of the code, to make it easier I put both classes in a single module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

from pprint import pformat
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Event, Lock
from copy import deepcopy

# Handles a single task
class Handler(Process):

  def __init__(self, task):

    super(Handler, self).__init__()
    self.__evt = Event()
    self.__task = deepcopy(task)
    self.__lock = Lock()

    print(f"Using Task: {task['id']}:\n {(task)}")
    print(f"{id(self)} ==> Initial Task ID: {id(self.__task)}")

  def update_task(self, task):
    print("*"*50)
    print(f"Updating the Task to {(task)}")
    with self.__lock:
      del self.__task
      self.__task = deepcopy(task)
    print(f"{id(self)} ==> New Task ID: {id(self.__task)}")
    print(f"The NEW TASK: {self.__task}")
    print("*"*50)

  def run(self):
    super(Handler, self).run()
    print("Starting the Main Thread")
    while not self.__evt.isSet():
      with self.__lock:
        print(f"Task ID: {id(self.__task)} => {self.__task}")
      self.__evt.wait(0.5)

  def stop(self):
    print(f"Stopping Thread")
    super(Handler, self).terminate()
    self.__evt.set()


# The main application
class Driver:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__evt = Event()
    self.__task = {
        'id': "Lonely Task",
        'name': 'Testing Item',
        'sources': []
    }

    self.__task['sources'].append(self.__gen_entry())
    print(f"The Task: {pformat(self.__task)}")
    handler = Handler(self.__task)
    handler.start()

    self.__evt.wait(1)
    print("Adding a new entry")
    self.__task['sources'].append(self.__gen_entry())
    self.__evt.wait(1)
    print("***********   Now Updating the Handler   ***************")
    handler.update_task(self.__task)
    self.__evt.wait(3)
    print("Now Stopping the Handler")
    handler.stop()
    print("Done!!")

  def __gen_entry(self):
    print("Generating entry")
    sz = len(self.__task['sources'])
    n = sz + 1
    return {
        'id': f"entry-{n}",
        'rx': f"Rx{n}",
        'fx': f"Fx{n}",
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
  Driver()
```

I tried using Thread and Process with the same result.  Tried with and without copy/deepcopy as well as deleting the initial object, with and without a Lock object.  I was expecting once I update the task, the subsequent print messages in the run method would reflect those changes, but it does not.  Here is a sample output:

```
./main_driver.py 
Generating entry
The Task: {'id': 'Lonely Task',
 'name': 'Testing Item',
 'sources': [{'fx': 'Fx1', 'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1'}]}
Using Task: Lonely Task:
 {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
139709461831752 ==> Initial Task ID: 139709454116256
Starting the Main Thread
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Adding a new entry
Generating entry
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
***********   Now Updating the Handler   ***************
**************************************************
Updating the Task to {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}, {'id': 'entry-2', 'rx': 'Rx2', 'fx': 'Fx2'}]}
139709461831752 ==> New Task ID: 139709454116328
The NEW TASK: {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}, {'id': 'entry-2', 'rx': 'Rx2', 'fx': 'Fx2'}]}
**************************************************
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Task ID: 139709454116256 => {'id': 'Lonely Task', 'name': 'Testing Item', 'sources': [{'id': 'entry-1', 'rx': 'Rx1', 'fx': 'Fx1'}]}
Now Stopping the Handler
Stopping Thread
Done!!
```

Comment: When using a thread I can't reproduce the problem. When using a process, the behavior is expected because the `Handler` object in the handler process is a separate copy of the object in the main process.

Comment: @MichaelButscher and you can't update the object even if you have a copy of it?  Will try to move the code back to use Thread, but I think you are right.

Comment: Look, I can't seem to run this code on my machine, but I'd seriously consider the name [mangling that happens when you use a dunder variable name](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).  If the variable is intended to be shared between threads or processes, then it's probably not class-private.

Comment: With processes you could establish a `multiprocessing.Pipe` or Queue between the processes. The main process can then send update information and the handler process waits in a separate thread for the message and updates the `Handler` object in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was some issues with the original code and someone changed it from Thread to Process.  Thanks to [Michael Bustcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher)'s comment, I changed it back to Thread, fixed what was broken and is now working.  Thank you very much Michael, I wish I could give the response credit to you.